# Can we tell the difference between a scalar field and a non-linear sigma model?

Tags: field-theory, higgs, topology, sigma-models

Suppose a $U(1)$ [non-linear sigma model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_sigma_model) field $\Sigma(x)$ take values on a circle. But if this circle is very large and the value don't vary so much, shouldn't this be almost identical to a scalar field. (As a very large circle looks very much like a line)

In other words, how do we know a scalar field like the Higgs is not just a non-linear sigma model in disguise? And what would be the consequences?

I suppose another way of phrasing it is as follows. A continuum of magnetic dipoles which face almost the same way but vary very slightly by angle might be approximated by a scalar field, with the scalar value giving the deviation of the angle. Likewise the reverse might be the case.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that it’s the topology of the circle, not its radius, that matters here.

Comment: @G.Smith, I'm not so sure. As in your dipole example, if the dipoles were mostly lined up but varied very slightly I suggest that could be modelled by a simple scalar field. We might only see a difference if the dipoles varied enough to do a full rotation.

Comment: The point of the model, I think, is to allow arbitrary orientations of the dipoles.

Comment: At the perturbative level the two are equivalent. You tell them apart by nonperturbative phenomena which involve the field value wrapping around the circle.

Comment: @knzhou That sounds right. What would we see in the Higgs case? Would we multiple Higgs of different masses for example? (Well that's what we would see if the dimension was on a circle. But that's different.) So I'm not sure. Maybe some special kinds of solitons?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Quantum effective action/potential in effective theories defined on a coset space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/508956/84967).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes, that looks very similar. I would still be interested to know what physical difference the two models would have?